# How to add stopwords to the default list in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to add more words to the default "*english*" stopwards, e.g., "inc", "incorporated", "ltd" and "limited". How can I achieve this?

My current code to create an index is as follows. Thanks.

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
           "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "filter": [ 
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "my_stop"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My test code

```
POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "House of Dickson<br> corp"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of "*english*" stopwords is the same as the set in [Standard Analyzer](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/53981795fd73e85aae1892c3c72344af7c57083a/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.java#L43).

You can create a file with these words and your additional stopwords and use `stopwords_path` option to point to this file (instead of `stopwords` setting):

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords_path": "stopwords/custom_english.txt"
        }
      },
      ...
}
```

You can find more information how the file should look like in [ES-docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html) (UTF-8, single stopword per line, file present on all nodes).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to create a custom stopwords file if I am using Elastic Cloud (don't have ES installed locally)?

Comment: I don't use Elastic Cloud but I think you need to request a support ticket in [Elastic Support Portal](https://support.elastic.co/customers/s/login/). Similar case here: [stopwords list upload](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/please-activate-synonyms-and-stopwords-list-upload/88124).

Answer (score 6):

I've been able to combine custom stopwords with the standard English using the following:

```
{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "custom_stop",
                    "english_stop"
                ]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "custom_stop": {
                "type":       "stop",
                "stopwords": ["custom1","custom2","custom3"]
            },
            "english_stop": {
                "type":       "stop",
                "stopwords":  "_english_"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used Matt's approach and it worked. Just one thing: first you have to close the index, send the put request, and then close the index.  You can use the following: curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/your_index/_close'