# How to add additional stop words to a Neo4j Full-text analyzer

Tags: search, neo4j, full-text-search

I'm doing full-text search and need to add to the list of stop words.

Something exactly like this in ElasticSearch: [How to add stopwords to the default list in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998259/how-to-add-stopwords-to-the-default-list-in-elasticsearch)

Is this posible without writing a custom analyzer as a plugin?
My index looks like this:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX productNameIndex FOR (n:Product) ON EACH [n.name] 
    OPTIONS {indexConfig: {`fulltext.analyzer`: 'danish' }}
```

Is it possible to do something like: `fulltext.stopwords: ['word1', 'word2']` or maybe `fulltext.stopwords: ./stopwords.txt`?

I havn't tried writing a custom plugin for Neo4j before, but that seems quite intimidating.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it is not possible to write a custom analyzer without writing a plugin. Luckily, you can copy some of the existing code for your custom analyzer.
For example, you can take a look at the covidgraph custom analyzer:

https://github.com/covidgraph/neo4j-additional-analyzers

```
@Service.Implementation(AnalyzerProvider.class)
public class SynonymAnalyzerProvider extends AnalyzerProvider {

    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "analyzer using synonyms";
    public static final String ANALYZER_NAME = "synonym";

    public SynonymAnalyzerProvider() {
        super(ANALYZER_NAME, new String[0]);
    }

    public Analyzer createAnalyzer() {
        try {
            return CustomAnalyzer.builder()
                    .withTokenizer(WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class)
                    .addTokenFilter(SynonymFilterFactory.class, "synonyms", "gene_symbols.txt", "ignoreCase", "true")
                    .addTokenFilter(StopFilterFactory.class, "format", "snowball", "words", "org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/english_stop.txt,org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/german_stop.txt", "ignoreCase", "true")
                    .addTokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
                    .build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String description() {
        return DESCRIPTION;
    }
}
```

Specifically, it seems that the stop-words are added in the following line:

```
.addTokenFilter(StopFilterFactory.class, "format", "snowball", "words", "org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/english_stop.txt,org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/german_stop.txt", "ignoreCase", "true")
```

Comment: You can also check this blog post on handling synonyms in your analyser https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2019/12/20/handling-synonyms-neo4j-full-text-search.html

Comment: Thank you - I think the hard part for me, is actually plugging in the plug in. Do you know that there is no way to do it without?